# Javascript replace all occurrences of reserved chars ".." with ". ." in a string results in full string being replaced

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to replace all occurrences of `..` with `. .` in a string. Basically, I don't want any `.` character being succeeded by another `.` character.

I've created this prototype function:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

However, whatever input I try, it results in the complete string being replaced with `.` characters, even though I've escaped the input and output string. What am I missing?

```
var description = 'hi there...how are you';
description = description.replaceAll('..', '. .');
description = description.replaceAll('\.\.', '\. \.');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\` is the escape character in string literals as well as regular expressions.

`"\.\."` produces the string value `..`, which, interpreted as regular expression, matches any two characters.

```js
console.log('\.\.');
```

You need to escape the `\` in the string literal to pass it along to the regular expression engine:

```
'\\.\\.'
```

produces the string value `\.\.`.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

var description = 'hi there...how are you';
console.log(description.replaceAll('\\.\\.', '. .'));
```

---

Having said that, using regular expression literal seems easier to me than hiding the `g` flag behind a custom method:

```
description.replace(/\.\./g, '. .');
```

No need to wonder about escape sequences.

---

Related: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/218196)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
description.replace(/(\.)(?=\.)/g,'. ');
```

where

- `(\.)(?=\.)` find dot after which is another dot ([positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

```js
var description = 'hi there...how are you';
description = description.replace(/(\.)(?=\.)/g,'. ');

console.log(description);
```